# Confused with SQL server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm using windows 8.1 64-bit, I installed visual studio 2012

1. can I install SQL server 2008 without problems.
2. does SQL server 2012 works with vs 2012
3. what is the best version of crystal report for vs2012

really sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

1- Can I install SQL server 2008 without problems. [Yes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2681562)

2- Does SQL server 2012 works with vs 2012. `Yes`

3- What is the best version of crystal report for vs2012. [This One](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

Comment: @ajjadHashmi I had installed (v. 13.0.7.x) - 64bit.msi, but it does'nt work why?

Comment: can you tell specifically what problem are you facing? Some installation issue or integration error?

Comment: @ajjadHashmi I have a project that include a .rpt it didn't recognize it, sorry for mybad English

Comment: can you post the exact error with the piece of code where the problem is occurring?